# Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Physical Fitness Stack Exchange](http://fitness.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How to overcome grip strength as sticking point for deadlifts?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18001/how-to-overcome-grip-strength-as-sticking-point-for-deadlifts)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What weight difference will tip an Olympic bar on a rack?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18105/what-weight-difference-will-tip-an-olympic-bar-on-a-rack)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Integrating running into strength training schedule](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18119/integrating-running-into-strength-training-schedule)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How many reps are ideal for increasing muscle mass?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18174/how-many-reps-are-ideal-for-increasing-muscle-mass)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is the effect of alcohol on the body?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18046/what-is-the-effect-of-alcohol-on-the-body)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Should I stay away from racing long distances if my main concern is health?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18070/should-i-stay-away-from-racing-long-distances-if-my-main-concern-is-health)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Is my routine okay?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18035/is-my-routine-okay)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Mechanism and recovery of lower back pain?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18077/mechanism-and-recovery-of-lower-back-pain)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How many pounds of water retention will be caused by 2300 mg of sodium?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18125/how-many-pounds-of-water-retention-will-be-caused-by-2300-mg-of-sodium)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How does the different loading techniques in bulagrian split squats compare?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18015/how-does-the-different-loading-techniques-in-bulagrian-split-squats-compare)

**Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 6)

---